# simulate two instances of Java SE on a single PC

Tags: java

I want to test my middleware (written in Java) on a single PC. That middleware  runs on one virtual device (that has JAVA SE) and the same middleware runs on second virtual device (that has Java SE).  I have a single PC with single operating system.

Would it be possible to simulate two instances of Java SE on a single PC with single operating system ?

Comment: Two instances of a Java process can be trivially executed on a single machine. What is an "instance of Java SE" ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to run 2 java _programs_ ?  I mean, you CAN install java twice, but that wouldn't solve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way to setup that type of test is using virtual machines.

Depending on your operating system, there are several options.

VirtualBox is easy to setup, works on many host operating systems, and is free.

Comment: Many thanks Eric. But, to install windowsXP on virtual machine, I need windowsXP disc. right ?

Comment: @PankeshPatel: You can get a free Windows XP VM from Microsoft if you have a licensed copy of Windows 7 http://blog.zeltser.com/post/15781390680/windows-xp-mode-for-vmware-virtualization